# merge two javascript objects to new key : value object

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the best way to merge these two objects into one and add keys as well. I tried a lot already but I am lost with how javascript works on objects and arrays... Who can guide me into the right direction? Either with plain JS or jquery.

**Object 1**

```
["EUR 1,99", "EUR 0,99", "EUR 4,99", "EUR 2,29", "EUR 1,43", "EUR 1,60", "EUR 1,79", "EUR 1,79", "EUR 1,39", "EUR 6,30", "EUR 1,43", "EUR 1,78", "EUR 1,90", "EUR 1,24", "EUR 1,41"]
```

**Object 2**

```
["Popken", "Lucky Animal", "mein-terrarium", "zooup", "zoofair", "XL-Hundeshop", "tiierisch-de", "Zoo Galaxie", "Petshop", "Danto GmbH", "Heimtierbedarf-Mazinke", "TIERKOSMOS", "Gazoma", "Zooheld", "dasko24"]
```

**Desired object**

```
[[Price="EUR 1,99",Name="Popken"],[Price="EUR 0,99",Name="Lucky Animal"],[Price="EUR 4,99",Name="mein-terrarium"], etc....]
```

Comment: What did you try? What problems did you have? Your desired "object" would error out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var newList = [];

for(var i=0; i<obj1.length; i++){
    newList.push({
        Price: obj1[i],
        Name: obj2[i]
    });
}
```

This has no error handling, and there may be a better way using the map function of the Array, but this should work as long as the length of both of your original objects are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Should be pretty straightforward. Assuming `arr1` is your array with prices, and `arr2` is your array with names:

```
var newarr = [],
    len = (number of items);

for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
    newarr.push({
        Price:arr1[i];
        Name:arr2[i];
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution using the zip-function in underscore.js

```
var prices = ["EUR 1,99", "EUR 0,99", "EUR 4,99", "EUR 2,29", "EUR 1,43", "EUR 1,60", "EUR 1,79", "EUR 1,79", "EUR 1,39", "EUR 6,30", "EUR 1,43", "EUR 1,78", "EUR 1,90", "EUR 1,24", "EUR 1,41"];

var products = ["Popken", "Lucky Animal", "mein-terrarium", "zooup", "zoofair", "XL-Hundeshop", "tiierisch-de", "Zoo Galaxie", "Petshop", "Danto GmbH", "Heimtierbedarf-Mazinke", "TIERKOSMOS", "Gazoma", "Zooheld", "dasko24"];

var result = _.map(_.zip(products, prices), function(arr) {
    return {
        Price: arr[1],
        Name: arr[0]
    };
});


console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic solution--it will "fold" an object so that you get a list of objects instead of an object of lists.

```
function refold_list_from_object(data) {
    "use strict"    
    var keys = Object.keys(data),
        descriptor = {configurable: true, enumerable: true, writable: true, value: null},
        properties = keys.reduce(function(p, k){
            p[k] = descriptor
            return p
        }, {}),
        nrecords = Math.max.apply(null, keys.map(function(k){return data[k].length})),
        records  = [], vi
    function makerecord() {
        return Object.create(null, properties)
    }
    function record_from_value_index(vi) {
        return keys.reduce(function(obj, k) {
            obj[k] = data[k][vi] || null
            return obj
        }, makerecord())
    }
    for (vi = 0; vi < nrecords; vi++) {
        records.push(record_from_value_index(vi))
    }
    return records
}
```

`data` should be an object with lists indexed by their field names:

```
var data = {
    Price: ["EUR 1,99", "EUR 0,99", "EUR 4,99", "EUR 2,29", "EUR 1,43", "EUR 1,60", "EUR 1,79", "EUR 1,79", "EUR 1,39", "EUR 6,30", "EUR 1,43", "EUR 1,78", "EUR 1,90", "EUR 1,24", "EUR 1,41"],
    Name: ["Popken", "Lucky Animal", "mein-terrarium", "zooup", "zoofair", "XL-Hundeshop", "tiierisch-de", "Zoo Galaxie", "Petshop", "Danto GmbH", "Heimtierbedarf-Mazinke", "TIERKOSMOS", "Gazoma", "Zooheld", "dasko24"],
    // An extra field to demonstrate padding:
    Description: ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz']
}

var recordlist = refold_list_from_object(data)
```

`recordlist` will look like this:

```
[
  {"Price":"EUR 1,99", "Name":"Popken",         "Description":"Foo"},
  {"Price":"EUR 0,99", "Name":"Lucky Animal",   "Description":"Bar"},
  {"Price":"EUR 4,99", "Name":"mein-terrarium", "Description":"Baz"},
  {"Price":"EUR 2,29", "Name":"zooup",          "Description":null},
  {"Price":"EUR 1,43", "Name":"zoofair",        "Description":null},
  {"Price":"EUR 1,60", "Name":"XL-Hundeshop",   "Description":null},
  {"Price":"EUR 1,79", "Name":"tiierisch-de",   "Description":null},
  {"Price":"EUR 1,79", "Name":"Zoo Galaxie",    "Description":null},
  {"Price":"EUR 1,39", "Name":"Petshop",        "Description":null},
  {"Price":"EUR 6,30", "Name":"Danto GmbH",     "Description":null},
  {"Price":"EUR 1,43", "Name":"Heimtierbedarf-Mazinke", "Description":null},
  {"Price":"EUR 1,78", "Name":"TIERKOSMOS",     "Description":null},
  {"Price":"EUR 1,90", "Name":"Gazoma",         "Description":null},
  {"Price":"EUR 1,24", "Name":"Zooheld",        "Description":null},
  {"Price":"EUR 1,41", "Name":"dasko24",        "Description":null}
]
```